# Javascript - Value instead of Reference during iterations

Tags: javascript, scope

Take this simple for for creating a List Component in ReactJs:

```
for (var key in this.props.code_values)
        {
            var current = this.props.code_values[key];
            var current_value = current.value;
            drop_choices.push(<ListItem
                                button
                                key = { current.id }
                                onClick = {(event) => this.makeSomethingWithValue(current_value)}
                              >
                                { current.value }
                              </ListItem>);
        }
```

The problem is current_value is calculated on Click so it will be always equals to the last current_value of the iteration.

For example:

```
code_values = [ { id : 1, value : 1}, { id : 2, value : 2} ]
```

Clicking on "1" will get "2" instead.

We are not "creating" html satic code but a component and OnClick is not "created" as an attribute during this iteration but "processed" only after the onClick event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scoping issue with var, try using `let` and `const` instead

```
for (let key in this.props.code_values)
    {
        const current = this.props.code_values[key];
        const current_value = current.value;
        drop_choices.push(<ListItem
                            button
                            key = { current.id }
                            onClick = {(event) => this.makeSomethingWithValue(current_value)}
                          >
                            { current.value }
                          </ListItem>);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some alternative ways you can approach this.

1. You may use `Function.prototype.bind` to bind the data to the event handler. Like `this.makeSomethingWithValue.bind(this, current_value)`.
2. You may use `Array.prototype.map` to iterate through the data you have and display them in this way within your return as below;

.

```
return (
  this.props.code_values.map(current => (
    <ListItem
      button
      key={current.id}
      onClick={(event) => this.makeSomethingWithValue(current.value)}
    >
      { current.value }
    </ListItem>
  ))
);
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop you should think about using `map` instead for better variable scoping. You might also consider passing the value into the component as a prop instead of the argument to the function.

Here's a mock-up of how I see the rest of your code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: props.data };

    // bind `handleClick`
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(e) {

    // take the value (textContent), coerce to a number and add 10 to it
    console.log(+e.target.textContent + 10);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>

         // `map` over the array in state
         {this.state.data.map(current => {
           return (
             <ListItem
               key = {current.id}

               // pass in value, and the function to be called onClick
               value={current.value}
               handleClick={this.handleClick}
             />
           )
         })}   
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function ListItem({ value, handleClick }) {
  return <li onClick={handleClick}>{value}</li>;
}

const data = [{ id: 1, value: 1}, { id: 2, value: 2}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```